# Progress to SQL Server Datetime Conversion with Pro2

Tags: sql-server, openedge, progress-4gl

We are using Pro2 to sync data from Progress to SQL Server. However, some datetime (or datetime offsets) are being converted into int32 and we cannot figure out the conversion. We have asked Progress but no reply. Curious if anyone is familiar with this.

I have found various articles regarding Oracle, Epoch, Julian, etc. but no definitive answers. Reference: [Working with MS SQL Server and ABL datetime data types (progress.com)](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-microsoft-sql-dataserver-117/page/Working-with-MS-SQL-Server-and-ABL-datetime-data-types.html)

For time columns, it is fairly straightforward. This code works:

```
select cast(dateadd(s, 86055, '00:00:00') as time(0)) -- returns 23:54:15
```

Here are some values with what should be the approximate date:

- 966188916  -- should be approx. 4/12/2010
- 1091012202 -- should be approx. 7/28/2014

Anyone know how to parse these?

Comment: Are you sure you have no typos in your examples? ( 1091012202 - 966188916 ) / ( 7/28/2014 - 4/12/2010 ) = 79606.6875 which is in the order of, but no where near close enough to the 86400 seconds in a 24 hour day.

Comment: Did Pro2 generate DDL that says that the field is datetime? Or is your complaint that Pro2 generated DDL saying that it is integer but you expected it to be datetime?